# How to ensure Client-Server Syncronization?

Tags: server, synchronization, client, client-server, cloud

I came across a client-server based question in which I am not sure how to answer. You're given hundreds of thousands of clients connected to a black box module, which speaks to a cloud.

Some of the operations that went through from the client to the server are:

1. set(a,5)
2. set(b,3)
3. get(a)
4. set(a,7)
5. set(c,4)

When we do the get(a) operation, we want to ensure that we have the most recent version of a. There is a delay between the time that the get can go through the cloud, and receive the value. In that time the next set(a,7) instruction will have already started. (Example, client 1 can do the get (a) command, and client 2 can do the set (a) command almost at the same time. This is where we want the synchronization to occur)

How can we design the black box to ensure we always have the most recent/accurate value of a?

My initial thought was to have a queue holding the incoming instructions inside the black box. When an instruction is complete, then we can begin the next instruction. But it seems as though this would delay the incoming instructions by a significant margin.

Any suggestions on how this can be done?